# How to remove white stains from the plastic bucket?

Tags: cleaning, water

Tap water in my house is hard water, due to which my buckets are becoming whitish. One of my buckets is blue and the other one transparent. Both looks clumsy due to white stains. Cleaning doesn't help. I even tried baking powder trick but it did not help.

So how can I remove white stains from the bucket and how to prevent it from forming again?

Images to show the type of white stains:

[image: blue bucket outside]

[image: blue bucket inside]

Comment: Can't see the reason for downvote. Will appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try vinegar solution to remove those stains. Follow these steps:

1. Mix white vinegar and water equally in a container. Try spray bottle if you can, though it is not necessary.
2. Apply this solution to stained area and allow it to soak for a while, about 15 minutes. If the stains are hard, allow solution soak for hours.
3. Rub it with a clean cloth or brush. You can repeat this process if required.

Another thing you can try is lemon. Rub the lemon over the stained area and then scrub it with brush. After that rinse the bucket with clean water.

For more, you can check [this](http://www.howtocleanstuff.net/how-to-remove-hard-water-stains-from-plastic/) out.

Comment: Any vinegar will work, cleaning vinegar maybe better than that meant for consumption, but +1, you wrote that I would have done.